# AIDE to support native android apps only?

Tags: android, c++, c, ide

I'd like to learn c++ programming on-the-go on my nexus 7 and i've found AIDE app. Does it support writing simple console apps on c++ or native android apps only?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [site](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-ide/13bj86n6pr/aide-aide-and-non-android-program/oldest), not at this moment. but i'm not sure about premium read this [site](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-ide/13bj86n6pr/aide-aide-and-non-android-program/oldest)

Answer (score 0):

According to the site AIDE supports only "Native Android Apps". Installed CppDroid instead, exactly what i need.